# Internet sharing via WiFi won't work (BSS stopping)

Tags: network, wifi, internet-sharing

I'm trying to start internet sharing on my mac mini (share ethernet to wifi).
Until a few days ago, it worked fine, and suddenly stopped working.

I'm pretty sure my "graphical" config is fine (with the System settings app). But there's something strange in the `/var/log/wifi.log`.

Whenever I start the sharing, it actually works very briefly, before stopping again (MAC addresses and stuff replaced with `<snip>`)

```
2014-05-05 11:47:37.974783 AM [wifid] <en1> Start BSS on <snip>
2014-05-05 11:47:37.974984 AM [wifid] <en1> Start Network
2014-05-05 11:47:38.058925 AM [wifid] <en1> Apple SWAP IE
Raw IE: 
<snip>
Signature Length: 4
Use for Beacon
Use for Probe Response

Host model identifier: Macmini6,2
Internet Connection Sharing Enabled

2014-05-05 11:47:38.107761 AM [wifid] <en1> Stop BSS on <snip>
2014-05-05 11:47:38.117333 AM [wifid] Change Interface Role on en1 with MAC <snip> to sta
2014-05-05 11:47:38.117608 AM [wifid] <en1> Maximum PHY Rate <450>
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: How about you disable your Snip.app (the screen snip)

Comment: These <snip> were inserted by me to hide sensitive data, it has nothing to do with the Snip app (unless they do some funky stuff with the network, but I seriously doubt so...)

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem, reseting the NVRAM and PRAM worked for me.

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1379